# Problems with window.postMessage on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain, postmessage

I have been stuck on this for hours.

I have a.html on http://example.com that contains an iframe with src to 
b.html on http://subdomain.example.com. a.html has some JS code
to postMessage to the iframe.

The code to postMessage is simple:

```
iframe_window.postMessage('message', iframe_element.src)
```

But this way, Chrome throws an error:

```
Unable to post message to http://subdomain.example.com. Recipient has origin null.
```

I have also tried:

```
iframe_window.postMessage('message', 'http://subdomain.example.com')
```

But NO LUCK!

This is the ONLY WAY it works:

```
iframe_window.postMessage('message', '*')
```

But I have heard '*' is not good to use.

No problems in Firefox.

Comment: Just to clarify, in your actual code, are you using a real website?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like this might be an issue with the child iframe not being loaded at the time the signal is sent, thus iframe.src doesn't have the proper value.

I did some testing and got the same error as you, but when I wrapped the postMessage call in a setTimeout and waited 100ms then there was no error, which tells me that this is an initialisation race condition.

Here's how I implemented a cleaner solution without the setTimeout:

Parent:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe")
      , _window = iframe.contentWindow

    window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {

        // wait for child to signal that it's loaded.
        if ( e.data === "loaded" && e.origin === iframe.src.split("/").splice(0, 3).join("/")) {

            // send the child a message.
            _window.postMessage("Test", iframe.src)
        }
    })

}, false)
```

Child:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // signal the parent that we're loaded.
    window.parent.postMessage("loaded", "*")

    // listen for messages from the parent.
    window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {

        var message = document.createElement("h1")

        message.innerHTML = e.data

        document.body.appendChild(message)

    }, false)

}, false)
```

This is a simple solution in which the child will signal to anyone that it's loaded (using "*", which is okay, because nothing sensitive is being sent.) The parent listens for a loaded event and checks that it's the child that it's interested in that's emitting it.

The parent then sends a message to the child, which is ready to receive it. When the child gets the message it puts the data in an <h1> and appends that to the <body>.

I tested this in Chrome with actual subdomains and this solution worked for me.

Comment: The very first sentence `It looks like this might be an issue with the child iframe not being loaded at the time the signal is sent` was the clue I needed to get the iframe communication  working... thanks!

Comment: Any idea what the actual condition for being "ready" is?  I don't think you have to wait all the way until DOMContentLoaded, but adding a listener as soon as the iframe starts loading is also too soon.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution is to wrap the postMessage inside iframe_element.onload function.